# pass multiple data on other activity from listview by useof firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a simple status Shayari application.

[image]

This is my first activity in which I retrieve data from Firebase in list view then I take custom text view so on text view click I open another activity name is--> Display_Full_Screen activity. In my Firebase database, there are many statuses I added and I retrieved successfully, but the problem is in other activity display only one selected status so in other Activity I put two buttons called forward and rewind. So when I click Forward button how can I get next status?

```
public class H_Status_Sub_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static ArrayList<String> list;
    private static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public static  DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private static  TextView textView;
    TextView txt_listview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_h__status__sub_);
        final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String main_cat = bundle.getString("name");
        String sub_cat = bundle.getString("name1");
        mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.h_s_s_listView);
        txt_listview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_listview);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Status").child(main_cat).child(sub_cat);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_listview, R.id.txt_listview, list);
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                ValueData = String.valueOf((dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                list.add(ValueData);

                mlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
               
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
        });

    }
    public void Display_Txt(View view){
        txt_listview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_listview);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Full Screen Text",txt_listview.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("list", String.valueOf(list));
        Intent intent = new Intent(H_Status_Sub_Activity.this, Display_Full_Screen_Activity.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

This is my other Activity In which I display particular text in full size, but In XML file there are two buttons called forward and rewind. When I click that button next status needs to appear, but I don't know how to do that.

```
public class Display_Full_Screen_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private  TextView txt_display_status;

 private Button 

btn_zoomin,btn_zoomout,btn_copy,btn_share,btn_forward,btn_rewind;


        private int x =20;
               private static DatabaseReference databaseReference = H_Status_Main_Activity.databaseReference;
          String Full_Screen_Text;
         String Status_List;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display__full__screen_);

        init();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Full_Screen_Text = bundle.getString("Full Screen Text");
        Status_List = bundle.getString("list");
            txt_display_status.setText(Full_Screen_Text);
    }
    
    public void Forward(View view){
        txt_display_status.setText(Status_List + 1);
        
    }
    public void Rewind(View view) {



    }
    public void Zoom_In(View view) {
        txt_display_status.getTextSize();
        txt_display_status.setTextSize((x++));
        txt_display_status.setTextSize(x);
    }
    public void Zoom_Out(View view) {
        txt_display_status.getTextSize();
        txt_display_status.setTextSize(x--);
        txt_display_status.setTextSize(x);

    }
    public void Copy(View view) {
        ClipboardManager clipboardManager =(ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Lable",txt_display_status.getText().toString());
        clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
        Toast.makeText(Display_Full_Screen_Activity.this, "Text Copied" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    public void Share(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "UNTOALD STORY");
        String shareText = txt_display_status.getText().toString();
        // shareText = shareText + "http://www.skynils.com/";
        // if you have live app then you can share link like below
        //shareText = shareText + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName();
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
    }
    public void whatsapp(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");
        // i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "UNTOALD STORY");
        String shareText = txt_display_status.getText().toString();
        // shareText = shareText + "http://www.skynils.com/";
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));

    }
    public void init(){
        txt_display_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_display_status);
        btn_zoomin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_zoomin);
        btn_zoomout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_zoomout);
        btn_copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_copy);
        btn_copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_copy);
        btn_share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
        btn_forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_forward);
        btn_rewind = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_rewind);


    }
}
```